# Finding the upper (convex) hull in higher dimension (3+)

Tags: algorithm, geometry, convex-hull

Sorry for my broken English.

I want to find the lower envelope of a plenty of linear equations.
This is mapped to the problem of finding the upper (convex) hull in its dual plane.

As I surveyed, there are a couple methods to find an upper hull, but they're only for 2-3 dimension.

However, my data is high dimensional, there are available libraries for finding (full) convex hulls up to n-dimension. I am thinking about how to extract the upper hull or lower hull from the full convex hull. Do you have any idea how to find this?

Answer (score 1):

Quick Hull is applicable to all dimentions. For more deatils read [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEIQFjAD&url=http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.117.405&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ei=H3O1UZfSDsjyrQeEx4GIAg&usg=AFQjCNHmO4DeKmds9u08GBWlpvNbNWE5-w&bvm=bv.47534661,d.bmk) pdf. It is a very easy generalisation of the 2d case.

Comment: Actually I use Quick Hull to find the convex hull, but I don't know how to determine each point of the outcome whether it is the lower hull or upper hull.

Comment: Put it in the equation of whatever defines 'up' and 'below' for n dimention and check its sign. If it is positive, include else reject. For 2d it is line, for 3d it is a plane. So you will need to find the equation of that line or plane, which can be done easily. Hope that helps(if it does, please accept the ans too :))

Comment: Note the paper is here now http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.117.405&rep=rep1&type=pdf and it doesn't say much about lower/upper method.