# How to efficiently find upper and lower hulls (w.r.t. some dimension) for Convex Hull in dimension d?

Tags: convex-hull

There are a few undefined things in the Wikipedia page like "upward ray".

A lot of explanations only deal with 2d. If you pick a dimension you can calculate the convex hull of the points with that dimension dropeed and I think that gives you the extreme points. But how do you determine (computationally, not with epsilon statements) whether the other points are above or below efficiently?

> In two dimensions, the convex hull is sometimes partitioned into two
> parts, the upper hull and the lower hull, stretching between the
> leftmost and rightmost points of the hull. More generally, for convex
> hulls in any dimension, one can partition the boundary of the hull
> into upward-facing points (points for which an upward ray is disjoint
> from the hull), downward-facing points, and extreme points. For
> three-dimensional hulls, the upward-facing and downward-facing parts
> of the boundary form topological disks.[7]

Comment: Maybe here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017858/finding-the-upper-convex-hull-in-higher-dimension-3